# reverse works, but redirect fails

Tags: django

I've read the docs like 5 times, I can't see whats missing here.

I have a situation where reverse() works fine, but the same params passed to redirect() fails with an error stating the address cannot be resolved.

```
reverse("app:submission_thanks", kwargs={ "data": survey.data.slug, "survey": survey.slug })

redirect("app:submission_thanks", kwargs={ "data": survey.data.slug, "survey": survey.slug })
```

My url is:

```
url(r'^(?P<data>[-\w]+)/(?P<survey>[-\w]+)/thanks/$',
         TemplateView.as_view(template_name="pasteur/submission_thanks.html"),
         name="submission_thanks",
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect has a different method signature:

```
redirect("app:submission_thanks", data=survey.data.slug, survey=survey.slug)
```

See [shortcut redirect examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples) in the Django docs.

---

Diving into the code a little: `redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)` calls `resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs)` which calls `urlresolvers.reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)`. So this is definitely correct.

You do not need to wrap the `args` in a list or `kwargs` in a dictionary when using the `resolve_url` or `redirect` shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Pass reversed url in redirect:

```
return redirect(
    reverse("app:submission_thanks",
    kwargs={ "data": survey.data.slug, "survey": survey.slug }))
```